# Guava : Is Cache.asMap().remove() better?

Tags: guava, google-guava-cache

I want to get & remove an item from `Cache`

```
final Cache<String, PendingRequest> pendingRequest = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();

// get first
pendingCall = pendingRequest.getIfPresent(key);
pendingRequest.invalidate(key); // then remove.
```

I also found another way

```
pendingCall = pendingRequest.asMap().remove(key);
```

Does `asMap` method clone all the items? Is it a heavy call?  Which manner is better if considering performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference between those calls because [`Cache#asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap--) is defined as:

> Returns  a view of the entries stored in this cache as a thread-safe map. **Modifications made to the map directly affect the cache**.

Calling `asMap()` *may* be slightly less performant (because it's possible a view has to be created) but the time is constant (and negligible) and is an implementation detail (see internal Guava [`LocalCache` and `LocalManualCache` classes](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java) for more details).

What's more important, [`Cache#invalidate(K)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#invalidate-java.lang.Object-) is more idiomatic and I'd recommend using it instead of map view methods *(edit after @BenManes' comment below)* if you don't need returned value associated with the key, otherwise use map view.

Comment: While more idiomatic, the view is useful in the situation where the removed value is needed. This operation is atomic, whereas his alternative of performing two operations is racy. The Cache interface provides an idiomatic and simple abstraction, while the view provides an escape hatch for more advanced needs.

Comment: @BenManes You're right, I didn't catch that OP needed to use removed value.